# Is it possible to apply the same scss styles to two mixins at the same?

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

Is it possible to apply the same scss styles to two mixins at the same time?

For example:

```
@include my-first-mixin; @include my-second-mixin{
    //my scss styles
}
```

The code above is what I am doing right now but one mixin always doesn't get the scss styles.

How can I solve this?

Comment: It is currently not possible: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1065

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
@mixin core-styles {
  // my scss styles
}

@include my-first-mixin {
  @include core-styles
}

@include my-second-mixin {
  @include core-styles
}
```